# Connecting to MySQL Server from Windows to Debian Linux

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a mysql server running on a virtual machine in debian linux, to which I am trying to establish a connection from MySQL Workbench in Windows. The MySQL user is 'dev'. I am unable to get this connection established possibly for one of these problems:

1. MySQL user doesn't allow connections from other than localhost. Although when I created the user account 'dev' in mysql I specified the connection string as `dev'@'%` to make sure connections from anywhere could be accepted.

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```
2. MySQL is not running on `port 3306`. But I check with netstat here's what I see:

   ```
   netstat -tlpn | grep :3306

   tcp        0        0 127.0.0.1:3306        0.0.0.0.:*        LISTEN        3687/mysqld
   ```

So this should not be the problem either.

1. The firewall is preventing access to mysql. I don't really know how to access and modify IPtables and ideally I'd love to have a nice front end or iptables. Not sure how to figure this out.

Please advise me on this problem!

Comment: Have you tried restarting mysql after creating the new user?

Comment: @Loïc Yes I've done that plenty of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you mysql-server configuration file also allows remote connection? it overides whatever you specify at database user level.

Answering your firewall issue, you can simply test the network connectivity by doing a telnet to you mysql-server as:

```
telnet YOUR_MySQL_SERVER_IP 3306
```

if telnet is able to connect then; mysql-servers' firewall has not blocked the traffic or your IP and there is some issue with mysql configuration. On the other hand if telnet connection fails then you may need to shutdown the iptables as:

```
service iptables stop
```

or you may add a firewall exception as per guided http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html

Comment: Can you guide me on where this file is and what properties are to be changes in that file?

Comment: it's in /etc/my.cnf usually

Comment: @EternallyCurious This text will guide you about MySQL configuration you need to allow remote connection to your mysql-server http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: @user3299142. No link in your comment.

Comment: @Loïc. Found that. Do you know properties and values to look for?

Comment: @EternallyCurious I apologize for the mistake, i have updated the comment.

Comment: @EternallyCurious yes, you must put your server IP address in bind-address (which value should actually be localhost)

Comment: @user3299142 Telnet can't connect. So I tried shutting down iptables using "service iptables stop" That returns an error: "iptables: unrecognized service". Interestingly, the stop start and restart mysqld functions that are shown in the page you pointed to don't work either

Comment: @EternallyCurious I need specific version of the linux distro you are talking about.

Comment: @EternallyCurious You may then manually stop the iptables since telnet is not connecting it menas firewall is blocking the port for sure. You can use the [link](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/shell-script-to-stop-linux-firewall/) this link where steps to flush the iptables have been written.